# Python matplotlib Removing Axes Margin

Tags: python, matplotlib

Removing padding of axes have been disccussed many times in stackoverflow.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d') 

ax.set_xticks([0,2,4,6,8,10])
ax.set_yticks([0,2,4,6,8,10])
ax.set_zticks([0,2,4,6,8,10])

ax.axes.set_xlim3d(left=0, right=10) 
ax.axes.set_ylim3d(bottom=0, top=10) 
ax.axes.set_zlim3d(bottom=0, top=10) 

plt.show()
```

This code generate the simple graph outline like this:
[image]

we can see the slight margin before and after 0 and 10 on the axes

[Correctly setting the axes limits in 3d plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986956/correctly-setting-the-axes-limits-in-3d-plots)

[Removing axes margins in 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488182/removing-axes-margins-in-3d-plot)

Above link provide some hacky way to solve this issue, but these won't work anymore.

Also, in github discussion,

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18052#issuecomment-792358896

suggested to remove certain line in library to remove padding, but those lines are updated
and no longer exist.

I saw https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/25272 where they said this issue will be solve in next version (3.9.0). But it will take a while for us to use.

Is anyone here has solved this issue in alternative way?